# Looking for the Bible Verse: "If any of you have more than one <some-thing> give that to another"

Tags: bible

"If any of you have more than one <some-thing> give that to another"

I'm pretty sure there's a Bible verse that reads something like this, I'm not sure what the <some-thing> is there, I keep thinking that Jesus said this, but I'm not entirely sure.

Can somebody help me out on what the verse is?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about verse identification. This type of question is off-topic by today's site standards: [Where's the line with the "verse-identification" tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4200)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you're thinking of [Luke 3: 11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%203:11) to me:

> He answereth and saith unto them, He that hath two coats, let him impart to him that hath none; and he that hath meat, let him do likewise.

This is part of John the Baptist's preaching to the people who came to him.